# fade in an image with jquery attr animate?

Tags: jquery, attr

When I click on a link I set an image src to display an image with this:

```
$('img').attr("src",(myPlaylist.playlist[myPlaylist.current].poster));
```

It works as it should, but I would like to animate the image so it fades in, how can I do that? I have tested with animate and opacity but somewhere I go wrong, I cant get it working.

So any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Post the code you have that doesn't quite do what you want, and explain both what it's doing and why that's not what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

First hide it:

```
$('img').css("display", "none");
```

Then set your src:

```
$('img').attr("src",(myPlaylist.playlist[myPlaylist.current].poster));
```

Then fade it in:

```
$('img').fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: No problems :) glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Load the image beforehand (perhaps in a div layered above) and hide it. Then animate it to show with fadeIn()

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('img').fadeIn(100,function(){
    $(this).attr("src",(myPlaylist.playlist[myPlaylist.current].poster));
});
```